# Spring H2 embedded database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2, embedded-database

I want to create an in-memory database populated with test data for fast testing, so I declare this bean in my configuration file, but I also want so set this properties:

```
MODE=MySQL
DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

but I don't know where to do it

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    return
        (new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder())
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2) //.H2 
        .addScript("classpath:db/H2.schema.sql")
        .addScript("classpath:db/H2.data.sql")
        .build();
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    return
        new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
        .setName("testDB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=MySQL") 
        .addScript("classpath:db/H2.schema.sql")
        .addScript("classpath:db/H2.data.sql")
        .build();
}
```

Comment: beat me on the minute :P

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.setName()`

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
return
    new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
    .setName("testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false")
    .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2) //.H2 
    .addScript("classpath:db/H2.schema.sql")
    .addScript("classpath:db/H2.data.sql")
    .build();
}
```

Note: I have not tried this myself, but found a clue on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42136338/290744) answer

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to wire DataSources using properties. This way, you can set the JDBC URL which can contain additional properties.

Answer (score 2):

The mode can be done via a SQL statement on H2, but I am pretty sure the `DB_CLOSE_DELAY` must be set as part of the URL which there is no easy hook into. You would be best just setting this in the application.properties/yml and let spring autoconfigure it

`jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL` would be the `spring.datasource.url` additional properties are available for the `schema` and `data`